# Omniauth localization in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

How do omniauth localize in ruby on rails project?

I want use **:ru** localization.

In my project I use:

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-vkontakte'
gem 'omniauth-mailru'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to localize? Is it the OAuth window/prompt/popup? Localizing that varies from service to service.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that omniauth allows you to provide translations for the messages that come out of it.  There don't seem to be any en.yml files in omniauth, omniauth-facebook or omniauth-twitter anyway.

I've only used omniauth with devise and devise provides a couple of omniauth-related messages which can be overridden, but they contain the untranslated error messages which come out of omniauth:

```
en:
  devise:
    omniauth_callbacks:
      failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
      success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."
```

These can be overridden in an app using devise by providing an en translations file containing these in config/locales in your app.  You can of course also provide a ru translations file and set config.default_locale = :ru in application.rb or use some other way to decide which locale to use.  You can see how devise builds an error message from an omniauth failure here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

You could use the same approach in your app without using devise, but as I say, the problem is that %{reason} would be the untranslated error (often an exception.message I think) from omniauth.

For general internationalisation, if you haven't read it already: [Rails i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

EDIT:

It sounded like you were asking about omniauth itself, but in case, as Ashitaka wondered in their comment, you were (also) asking about telling the services you call which locale to use, you've probably seen in the docs, but just for the sake of completeness it does indeed vary by service.  For example, omniauth-facebook lets you add a locale parameter to the facebook call (e.g. locale=ru_RU) and omniauth-twitter lets you add a lang parameter to the twitter call (e.g. lang=ru).

Answer (score 0):

If you browse under `app/config/locales` dir, there is a file `en.yml`. It is for english locale. If you would like to add other languages, just create (in your case) `ru.yml` file and place translations there.

This [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) is a nice staring point.

Recently I have tried another interesting approach : [phrasing gem](https://github.com/infinum/phrasing).